# Selection by adjacent polygon features

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins

I have a large polygon shapefile with lots of features from a model output, I need to remove anomalous features which are joined by a single vertex and part of a cluster of two. (example highlighted below)

[image: pic]

Comment: What do you mean by « ...part of a cluster »? If polygons touch each other, they are necessarily part of a cluster, aren't they?

Comment: Sorry I mean clusters as my own terminology just to describe a groups of polygon that touching each other. Wasnt aware it would be defined as something else.

Comment: So two polygons only, with one common vertex between them only?

Comment: Yip, can you think of a way to select them separately?

Comment: Do you want to use code or not? Both are possible, but the non-code option has quite a few steps involved.

Comment: Idealy not using code as i'm not brilliant at it/inexperienced in using it - unless theres a good guide handy. Not against using it though.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED 31 May 2016 - Removed need for sum by table by using sum in Spatial Join instead, added step 2.

This is an approximate answer, because there is a small possibility of a mistake if two "clusters" of polygons are very close together, it is long, but hopefully quite straight forward.

1. Buffer the polygon layer by a small amount, tick the dissolve box, this   creates a buffer layer "Buffer1".
2. Use Multi part to single part on Buffer1 to seperate out the patches.
3. Add an integer column to Buffer1 called "Counter" and set all rows to 1.
4. Spatial join the polygon layer to Buffer1 using the "sum" option.
5. Add a column to Buffer1 called "APair", select all those cases in Buffer1 where Sum-Counter is greater than 1 and less than 3 and set APair to 1.
6. Spatial Join Buffer1 back onto the polygon layer.

Now you have a way to identify all the isolated pairs of triangles using APair. Highlight them to check it has worked. If you want, copy these pairs to a new data set to lower the subsequent calculation load considerably.

Next you need to remove those with more that one vertex in common.

7. Use Feature Vertices to Points (Data management) to extract all the vertices and make a small buffer around the vertices "PointBuff1". Do not use dissolve.
8. Convert the triangle polygons to lines ("TLines1").
9. Add a column LnCount to TLines1 and set its value to 1.
10. Spatial join the TLines1 to PointBuff1 using sum option - PointBuff2.
11. Spatial join PointBuff2 to Buffer1 using the sum option - Buffer2.

Now you have buffers around pairs of triangles, with a value showing how many polygon edges connect the vertex points  there in (called something like sumof_sumof_LnCount). If the connection between triangles is at two vertices (i.e. there is a common edge) the value will be 20, if the connection is only at one corner the value will be 16.

12. Select by location all those polygons under Buffer2 with a vertex-edge count of 16 and delete.

NB > The reason this is so long winded is that shapefiles are not topologically structured. If you have a topological data structure it is simple : find adjacent pairs and calculate the Euler Character of the graph.

Comment: NB2 > if you think that the buffer may pick up on very proximate but separate patches use intersect on Buffer 1 to find any overlaps.

Comment: Wooaa... what just happened? It has skipped  steps 5 to 10 on posting. Here they are > 5) Use Summary Statistics to get the Sum of "Counter" with ID as the case field. - "SumTab1"
6) In the SumTab1 select all those cases where Sum-Counter is greater than 1 and less than 3 and export to a table "PairTab1"
7) Join this table back to the polygon table using the polygon ID.
8) Add a column to the polygon table called "APair"
9) Set "APair" to 1.
10) Remove all joins.

Comment: Not sure what went wrong with your formatting but I have fixed it as best I can.

Comment: Thanks for your response, we're just a bit stuck on the second step. Just clarifying - when you mean do a spatial join it is "join attributes by location". Does your buffer layer have only the one attribute/row?

Comment: Ah, I missed a step - you need to use "mutli part to single part' between step 1 and step two. I will edit my answer.